# Plot a line passing through two given points in 3D space

Tags: plotting, geometry

How can I plot straight line passing through two given points in 3D coordinates?

For example, given the points M1: (2, -2, 0) and M2: (1, -3, -5)

```
(x-2)/(1-2)  == (y+2) / (-2+3) == (z-0) / -5
(x-2)/-1 == (y+2)/1 == z/-5
```

I did some attempts with `Solve` and `Reduce`, but they didnt give the results I expected.

Comment: Use `ParametricPlot3D[]` with the usual vector equation `(1 - t) pt1 + t pt2`. Alternatively, look up `Line[]` or `InfiniteLine[]`.

Comment: Thanks. I have one question more... is there are some possibilities to obtain this result in just Plot3D, not in the Parametric ? i used  y /. Solve[(x - vec2[[1]])/vec[[1]] == (y - vec2[[2]])/vec[[2]], y]   to obtain same result in 2d plots.

Comment: `Plot3D[]` produces *surfaces*, and a line is not a surface.

Comment: Another alternative is to use on the the graphics commands:, for instance, `Graphics3D[Line[{{2, -2, 0}, {1, -3, -5}}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**:

*Arbitrary data*

```
p1 = {0, 0, 0}  (* This defines point no. 1*)
p2 = {0, 0, 10} (* This defines point no. 2*)
```

*Process*

```
Graphics3D[Line[{p1, p2}]]
```

**Reference:**

[Graphics3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)
[Line](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html)